# How to read entire PDF with GhostScript.NET

Tags: asp.net, ghostscript.net

I have a web page that displays images to users.  The display is meant to confirm that the user has uploaded the proper documentation.  Due to security requirements I've decided to embed the images in the html (this allows all images to have the same URL).  My application allows a few different types of files to be used, but my problem is with pdf files.

I am using Ghostscript.NET and Ghostscript to read my pdfs and convert them into images so that I can embed them.  My Ghostscript implementation is reading the files, but I am only able to display the first page.  My question: how can I display the entire pdf, either on one page, or multiple pages?

I have tried:

```
do
            {
                img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                returnString += Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                pageNumber++;

            } while (pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount);

            _rasterizer.Close();
            ms.Close();

            return returnString;
```

The above implementation generates a very large string but, the 'broken image' icon displays on the webpage.

```
        do
        {
            img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            Session["NextPage"] = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

            if (pageNumber > 1)
            {                  
                Response.Write("<script>");
                Response.Write("window.open('ImageDisplayMultiPage.aspx')");
                Response.Write("<" + "/script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Image3.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Session["NextPage"];
            }

            pageNumber++;

        } while (pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount);

        _rasterizer.Close();
        ms.Close();
```

This implementation successfully opens windows equal to the amount of pages in the document, but displays the first page of the pdf on all but one webpage.  The remaining webpage displays the 'broken image' icon.  FYI the webpages this method opens use:

```
Image3.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Session["NextPage"];
```

to write to it's pages, which is set up properly.

Again, the goal is to convert the entire pdf to a base64 string.  It can be displayed on multiple pages, or it can be displayed on one page.  Do you know how to do this?

The file size is limited on upload to 5mb, I'm guessing the largest pdf will be 5 pages, but that's not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to close the rasterizer at the end of the loop and re open it when the loop began.  This implementation is working:

```
        List<string> pagesOfPDF = new List<string>();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, localDllInfo, false);
        int numberOfPages = _rasterizer.PageCount;
        _rasterizer.Close();

        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++)
        {
            _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, localDllInfo, false);
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            img = null;
            string returnString;
            img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            returnString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            pagesOfPDF.Add(returnString);
            ms.Close();
            _rasterizer.Close();
        }

        foreach (string image in pagesOfPDF)
        {
            imageDisplay.Controls.Add(new HtmlImage()
            {
                Src = "data:image/png;base64," + image,
                Alt = ""
            });
        }

        ms.Close();
```